# How do I stop / from being escaped in json?

Tags: karate

**For some reason a variable with a `/` character get converted to a `\/`, how do I prevent this?**

1. I start a echo server that listens on localhost:3000 by running `npx http-echo-server`
2. I execute the following:

code:

```
* def CHALLENGE_USER = '/abc/user'
* def loginJson = { user: '#(CHALLENGE_USER)' , name: 'Some Name'}
* print loginJson
* def TEST_URL = 'http://localhost:3000'
Given url TEST_URL+'/session/loginresponse'
And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
And request loginResponseJson
And method put
Then status 200
```

It prints `{ "user": "/abc/user", "name": "Some Name" }` like I expect.

3. The http server logs show "--> {"user":"/schemes/ATT_5_55/CH_1","name":"Some Name"}"
4. Karate shows the result of the echo `{"user":"\/abc\/user","name":"Some Name"}`

I have tried:

- def CHALLENGE_USER = '/abc/user'
- def CHALLENGE_USER = "/abc/user"
- def CHALLENGE_USER = '/abc/user'
- def CHALLENGE_USER = '//abc//user'

also setting the variable after the fact does not work:

```
* def loginJson = {  name: 'Some Name'}
* loginJson.user = CHALLENGE_USER
```

Comment: Escaping slashes is redundant but legal. There is no cause for concern. You need to modify your test to take this into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is legal as per the JSON spec: [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580647/143475)

And the Java libraries we use does that.

Does your server have a problem ? If so - then you have a bug that Karate surfaced.

And if you really want to have full control over the request, please use `text` but IMO it may be a waste of time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68344856/143475

Comment: Oh my, I was not aware of the JSON spec forward slash escaping.
It seems like a feature not a bug... :-)

Answer (score 1):

A **nasty workaround**, please forgive me [Peter Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143475/peter-thomas).

You can convert the json to a string and then remove the \ characters.

*I only have one use case for this thank goodness.*

```
* def CHALLENGE_USER = '/abc/user'
* def loginJson = { user: '#(CHALLENGE_USER)' , name: 'Some Name'}
* string json = loginJson
* def loginJsonText = json.replaceAll("\\", "")
* print loginJson
* def TEST_URL = 'http://localhost:3000'
Given url TEST_URL+'/session/loginresponse'
And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
And request loginJsonText
And method put
Then status 200
```