# unable to convert raw data to json format after replacing the \(slash)

Tags: testing, karate

I am  passing the raw data and removing unwanted slash and trying to convert to json format, unable to proceed.

```
json spot = {"LoginDetails":"{\"firstName\":\"abcd\",\"lastName\":\"\",\"middleName\":\"\",\"phoneNumber\":\"6944000000\",\"phoneCountryCode\":\"+91\",\"dob\":\"1945-02-22\"}"}
string a = spot
def ab = a.replace("\\", "")
json st = ab
```

And request st
When method POST
Then status 200

Getting error

> net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected token f

How to resolve this issue and convert the above payload into json format?

NOTE: After conversion to json firstname, phonenumber should be passed dynamically from the preceding API calls.

Comment: I don't understand this question at all so I pass. see if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68411097/143475

Answer (score 0):

If u want escape slash with json, you could try

```
a.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\")
```

or change it to unicode.

```
a.replaceAll("\\", "\u005C")
```

Both of them is workable for browser but not sure for karate, maybe you need change a bit by yourself.