# "\" is getting upended before "/" in post method karate

Tags: json, encoding, karate

There is a refrence file data.json where variable name is fileURL with value as

```
"fileURL" : "https://Fats-app-files.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ilnwms.json_1683633784367.json"
```

From my feature file i am reading this variable and passing in request parameter value "data".

```
{
    "facility": "OCLAS1",
    "s3_url": "url"
}
```

```
Scenario: Running the cron for ILN Report
    Given path '/v1/notification/iin'
    And header Accept-Encoding = 'gzip, deflate, br'
    And header Accept = '*/*'
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    And header X-MW-TOKEN-EX = token


    * json aa = iinData.fileURL
    And set requestParams.facility = data.facility
    And set requestParams.s3_url = aa
    And request requestParams
    * print requestParams
    When method post
```

in post method i am getting this inside data value.

```
https:\/%2Fats-app-files.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\/ilnwms
```

I am expecting the same url which i am reading from the refrence file.

Comment: This is absolutely normal. Refer this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68411097/143475