Karate Framework: Automatic Escaping of Backslashes in Input Tokens (e.g., \x2D, ab\c12, ab\c12\34)
I am encountering an issue in the Karate Framework where backslashes in input tokens are automatically escaped during JSON serialization. Specifically:

If the input token contains sequences like \x2D, the value assigned to the JSON object gets serialized as \x2D instead of the expected \x2D.

Similarly, for inputs such as ab\c12 or ab\c12\34, the backslashes are doubled, resulting in ab\c12 and ab\c12\34 respectively, rather than preserving the original format.


* def statetoken = '004oOSPtA\\x2DzhrSKFJdcxribrZFrNbhVuDw0CwdA6lZ'
* def authRequest =
"""
{
  "stateToken": "#(statetoken)"
}
"""
* print 'Constructed authRequest:', authRequest



Expected Behavior:
For the above inputs:

Input: 004oOSPtA\x2DzhrSKFJdcxribrZFrNbhVuDw0CwdA6lZ
Expected: "stateToken": "004oOSPtA\x2DzhrSKFJdcxribrZFrNbhVuDw0CwdA6lZ"
Input: ab\c12
Expected: "stateToken": "ab\c12"
Input: ab\c12\34
Expected: "stateToken": "ab\c12\34"

Actual Behavior:
The backslashes are being doubled in the JSON, resulting in:

"stateToken": "004oOSPtA\x2DzhrSKFJdcxribrZFrNbhVuDw0CwdA6lZ"
"stateToken": "ab\c12"
"stateToken": "ab\c12\34"

Debugging Attempts:


karate.eval():

Attempted to treat the value as raw JSON using karate.eval('"' + statetoken + '"'), but it still adds escaping during serialization.

Replacing Backslashes:

Tried statetoken.replace('\', '\\') to pre-process the backslashes, but this results in even more escaping (\\).

Constructing Raw JSON:

Manually constructed the JSON object as a string to bypass Karate's serialization, but the escaping persisted.

Question:
How can I ensure that the backslashes in statetoken remain as-is, without being auto-escaped during serialization? Is there a specific approach in Karate to handle raw strings or prevent this automatic escaping?


The escaping of JSON is as per the spec and if your server cannot decode it, you have a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68411097/143475
Anyway if you really want full control - you can form the JSON yourself:
* def token = '004oOSPtA\\x2DzhrSKFJdcxribrZFrNbhVuDw0CwdA6lZ'
* def body = `{ "stateToken": "${token}" }`

* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* header content-type = 'application/json'
* request body
* method post

The request seems to be what you expect:
1 > POST https://httpbin.org/anything
1 > content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
1 > Content-Length: 65
1 > Host: httpbin.org
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/17.0.1)
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
{ "stateToken": "004oOSPtA\x2DzhrSKFJdcxribrZFrNbhVuDw0CwdA6lZ" }

But the server clearly could not process the body as valid JSON, see the value of the json key is null:
1 < 200
1 < Date: Tue, 03 Dec 2024 05:53:40 GMT
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 < Content-Length: 542
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{ \"stateToken\": \"004oOSPtA\\x2DzhrSKFJdcxribrZFrNbhVuDw0CwdA6lZ\" }", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "65", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/17.0.1)", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-674e9ce4-239d2a7a27bdacd8763b4548"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "method": "POST", 
  "origin": "49.206.1.77", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}

You can try this and see the difference, it looks to me that \x2D is the encoding for a - or hyphen.
* def token = '004oOSPtA\x2DzhrSKFJdcxribrZFrNbhVuDw0CwdA6lZ'
* def body = { "stateToken": "#(token)" }

* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* request body
* method post

